# xrld python get cell's row and column labels

Tags: python, excel, label, xlrd

```
thebook = open_workbook(file_to_import)
thesheet = thebook.sheet_by_index(0)
print "show that there is value in the sheet: %s" % thesheet.cell(1,1).value
print "there is nothing in thesheet.col_label_ranges:"
print thesheet.col_label_ranges

for crange in thesheet.col_label_ranges:
    rlo, rhi, clo, chi = crange
    for rx in xrange(rlo, rhi):
        for cx in xrange(clo, chi):
            print "Column label at (rowx=%d, colx=%d) is %r" \
                (rx, cx, thesheet.cell_value(rx, cx))
```

I am trying to get the row and column label of a specific cell, and I found the code that loop through col_label_ranges that I used it above. However when I run this code, the result I got is:

```
show that there is value in the sheet: Katherine
there is nothing in thesheet.col_label_ranges:
[]
```

Please tell me what's going wrong, and what should I do to read the row and column label of a cell?

Answer (score 0):

So `.col_label_ranges` is empty - Have you actually got any label names? Everything implies that you haven't.

Note the doc's for xlrd mention:

> List of address ranges of cells containing column labels. These are
>   set up in Excel by Insert > Name > Labels > Columns.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand that. 
Infact I want to get the default label or the address that show up in the excel sheet. For example: at cell (0,0) I want to get "A1".
I found an answer for that is:
<code>    from xlrd import open_workbook ,cellname
    thebook = open_workbook(file_to_import)
    thesheet = thebook.sheet_by_index(0)

    for i in range(0, thesheet.nrows):
        for j in range(0, thesheet.nrows):
            print "value at cell %s is: %s" % (cellname(i,j), thesheet.cell(i,j).value) <\code>

Comment: @HuongOrchid Ahh - the cellname or reference - ahhh okay... yup - that's using `xlrd.cellname` as you've discovered.